Show that the vector field $X(p)$ satisfies $X(p)=(dl_p)_{(1,0)}(u)$, where $u=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_{(1,0)}$
Let $S^1$ be the unitary circle with Lie group structure given by multiplication
$$e^{it}e^{is}=e^{i(s+t)}$$
For $p\in S^1$, consider the diffeomorphism $l_p:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ associated with left multiplication. Show that the field $X:S^1\rightarrow TS^1$ defined in $p=(x,y)$ by
$$X(p)=-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_p$$
satisfies $X(p)=(dl_p)_{(1,0)}(u)$, where $u=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_{(1,0)}$
(Hint: Write $l_p$ as the restriction of a rotation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the circle and calculate its differential in $T\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that it preserves the tangent bundle of the circle)
My attempt:
During the resolution, I have switched between the notations $(x,y)$ and $e^{i\theta}$ for points in the circle, and maybe this is what caused problems, however I don't know why.
Anyway, let $p=e^{i\alpha}$. Then, for $e^{i\theta}\in S^1$, $l_p(e^{i\theta})=e^{i(\theta+\alpha)}$
Let $c:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\rightarrow S^1$ such that $c(0)=(1,0)$ and $c'(0)=u$
c is a function with outputs in the circle, therefore $c(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}$ for some function $\theta(t)$
$(1,0)=c(0)=e^{i\theta(0)}$
Switching notations: $e^{i0}=c(0)=e^{i\theta(0)}\Rightarrow\theta(0)=0$
$u=c'(0)=\frac{d}{dt}e^{i\theta (t)}|_{t=0}=e^{i\theta(0)}\frac{d}{dt}i\theta(t)|_{t=0}=ie^{i0}\theta'(0)=i\theta'(0)\Rightarrow\theta'(0)=-iu$
This is the first problem I encountered. I don't understand how $\theta'(0)$ can be a multiple of $u=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_{(1,0)}$ since $\theta$ is a function from a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. But continuing:
$(dl_p)_{(1,0)}(u)=\frac{d}{dt}l_p(e^{i\theta(t)})|_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}e^{i(\theta(t)+\alpha)}|_{t=0}=e^{i(\theta(0)+\alpha)}\frac{d}{dt}(i\theta(t)+i\alpha)|_{t=0}=e^{i\alpha}i(-iu)=e^{i\alpha}u=pu=p\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_{(1,0)}$
The answer i found is the vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_{(1,0)}$ multiplied by a point of the circle, wich I don't think makes sense.
I don't know how to use the hint. I did write $l_p$ as a rotation, but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Would the differential be different had I treated $l_p$ as a restriction from a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $S^1$ instead of just a rotation in $S^1$? Also, I didn't try to show it preserves the tangent bundle of the circle because I don't know how.
Thank you.

You have to be careful when differentiating curves with values in manifolds. Looking at it the traditional "calculus" way, the curve given by $t\mapsto e^{it}$ has the derivative $ie^{it}$. At $t=0$ for example this corresponds to the value $i\in\mathbb{C}$. Now thinking of derivatives of curves as being mapped into $TS^1$, we can identify $T_{(1,0)}S^1$ with a subspace of $T_{(1,0)}\mathbb{R}^2$. As the coordinate chart of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by the identity map, we can think of the coordinate frame $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ as simply being equated to the cannonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The coordinates of $i=\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}e^{it}$ are precisely $(0,1)$, so the "differential geometry version" of the derivative of the curve would be $\frac{d}{dt}_{t=0}e^{it}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}_{(1,0)}$. Now that we understand the toy example, we can look at the first problem you've encountered. You've evaluated the "calculus" derivative. So with your calculation $u=i$ and not $\partial/\partial y$. If we now look at what the actual equality is saying, it's $\theta'(0)=-iu=-i^2=1$, which is fully acceptable. Now onto the differential geometry calculation. Note that in this case $\frac{d}{dt}\theta(t)=\theta'(t)\frac{d}{dt}$ where $\theta'$ denotes the standard derivative of the real function $\theta$ and $\frac{d}{dt}$ the standard coordinate frame on $\mathbb{R}$. So our calculation goes as follows: Using the chain rule and the definition of the differential map on manifolds, one obtains
$$
  u=\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}e^{i\theta(t)} = \big[\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}\theta(t)\big]e^{i\theta(t)} = \theta'(0)u.
$$
Since $\theta'(0)$ is a real number and $u\neq 0$, we get $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\theta(t)=1\frac{d}{dt}_{t=0}$, which doesn't contradict any of our preconceptions.
A similar problem occurs in your second calculation. You're simply trying to evaluate the "standard derivative" while completely forgetting that you're supposed to interpret them as elements of $TS^1$. I recommend redoing the calculation but carefully examining what vectors come out in $TS^1$. By that I of course mean as a linear combination of $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial y$.
